# Java -- Printing stuff twice

Tags: java, loops, output

My program asks the user to enter a choice (1, 2, 3, or 0). Choice 1 asks the user to enter feet and inches. Choice 2 asks the user to enter centimeters. 
Each time I do this, the program prints double of what I need (please see below):

```
Enter choice: 1

Enter feet: 12

Enter inches: 2

Enter feet: 12 //This second part should not happen

Enter inches: 2
```

I have tried commenting out the `addConversion(...)` line, but this does not allow me to print choice 3 properly. When I comment out `System.out.println(feetInchesToCm())` my conversion for that case is not printed.

The main function of my code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
    int choice;

    do
    {
        displayMenu();

        choice = getInteger("\nEnter choice: ", 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            addConversion(feetInchesToCm());
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(feetInchesToCm());
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            addConversion(cmTofeetInches());
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(cmTofeetInches());
        }
        else if(choice == 3) 
        {                       
            if(_prevConversions == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(_prevConversions != null)
            {
                for(int i = 1; i <= _numConversions; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Conversion # " + i + ": ");
                    System.out.println(_prevConversions[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }while(choice != 0);
    if(choice == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
        System.exit(0); //Ends program
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What is `feetInchesToCm` ?

Comment: Downvoters, if you are going to downvote please give feedback to help the OP understand what he did wrong.  Downvoting without a cause only pushes people away from the site.  We want people to come back but ask useful and meaningful questions.

Comment: @Dale No one is obligated to comment after downvoting, but I did because the questions is basically asking us to debug and many vital details are missing.

Comment: I am wondering why the question got -4 votes O.o

Comment: @Dale Agreed. My answer addresses the problem too, even if enough information isn't provided

Comment: Your right that no one is obligated to do so, however, it does help the site retain people and helps others understand what they did wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You've explicitly called your method twice

Save the return value, or don't call it again.

For example

```
  if(choice == 1)
    {
        int cm = feetInchesToCm();
        addConversion(cm);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(cm);
    }
```

Or, if you don't need to save the value in order to print it, just call addConversion directly on the returned value

```
  if(choice == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        addConversion(feetInchesToCm());
    }
```

Comment: `addConversion` is called, but you remove it from the statement branches? Do you know for sure it's `feetInchesToCm` that's causing it? You might want to wait for the OP to clarify what it is before answering.